# Angularjs: ng-pattern and email validation

Tags: angularjs

My Email regex is

```
EMAIL_REGEXP = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

The following code doesn't work because ng-pattern thinks that
 `my regex is : "/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"` because that's where it first encounters the end quote ". But we know that my regex is what I mentioned above.

```
 <label>Email Address:</label>

  <input type="email" name="userEmail" ng-model="email"  ng-pattern= "/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/" required />



  <div ng-messages="exampleForm.userEmail.$error">
      <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
      <div ng-message="pattern">Must be a valid 10 digit phone number</div>
      <div ng-message="email">Your email address is invalid</div>
    </div>
```

**Is there a fix for this?**

```
Thanks,
Srikanth
```

Comment: Use a backslash to escape the double quotes.

Comment: /"/? or /"? or "/?  I tried all these and it won't work. E.G. /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@/"/]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@/"/]+)*)|(/"/.+/"/))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/

Comment: Use the \ symbol, not /

Comment: Doesn't work but thanks.

Comment: You must not be using it correctly. If you have this string: "foo"bar", the first set of double quotes will be used because the middle quote isn't escaped, which is what's breaking your regex. Alternatively, if you have: "foo\"bar", then the string will come out as foo"bar because the middle quote has been escaped and ignored. You need to escape all of the middle quotes in your regex string so that the entire regex is read as the string and not broken half way through. Alternatively, just wrap the whole thing in single quotes and that should solve it cause there are no single quotes.

Comment: Please check my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this new pattern.
I have changed a pattern.

Email Address:

```
  <input type="email" name="userEmail" ng-model="email"  ng-pattern='/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/' required /> 

  <div ng-messages="exampleForm.userEmail.$error">
      <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
      <div ng-message="pattern">Your email address is invalid</div>
  </div>
```